# Lexicographic order.

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Write the first 12 monomials K [x, y] and arrange them using:
2. Write all monomials of degree <3 in K [x, y, z] and arrange them using:

a) lexicographic order;

b) lexicographic order with gradation.

As far as I know how to calculate it, I don't know if they should be any monomials, for example $2xy$, $xy^ 2$. to point 1. And to point 2. it's supposed to be $xy^2z, x^2yz$.

[image]

Comment: What is ${}K{}$? And can a "monomial" in your setting have a coefficient $\ne 1$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial.  Type `$xy^2$` to get $xy^2$

Comment: I think it might be $ \neq 1$.